# ArrayList of arrays keeps overwriting my previous arrays with the newest array being added

Tags: java, xml, static, replace, arraylist

Im parsing an xml file.  My XML handler, my object that holds an Arraylist of arrays, and the main class that runs everything and prints it.  The problem is, every time I add an array to my arraylist, it changes the all of the previously added arrays to the same as the current.  I thought it was just a static problem but once I took static out of everything it still is doing the same thing.  Help please I need to have this done asap.

Here is my handler:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

public int counter = 0;
public String[] part = new String[4];
Boolean currentElement = false;
String currentValue = null;
public SitesList sitesList = null; /this used to be static

public SitesList getSitesList() {  //this used to be static
    return sitesList;
}

public void setSitesList(SitesList sitesList) { //this used to be static
    MyXMLHandler handle = new MyXMLHandler(); //thats why the object
    handle.sitesList = sitesList;
}

/**
 * Called when tag starts ( ex:- <name>text</name> -- <name> )
 */
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("string-array")) {
        /** Start */

        String attr = attributes.getValue("name");
        sitesList = new SitesList(attr);
    }

}

/**
 * Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>text</name> -- </name> )
 */
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    currentElement = false;

    /** set value */
    if (counter == 4) {
        sitesList.addPart(part);
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        part[counter] = currentValue;
        counter++;
    }
    currentValue = "";

}

/**
 * Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>text</name> -- to get
 * text Character )
 */
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if (currentElement) {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }

}

}
```

Here is my SitesList object

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/** Contains getter and setter method for varialbles */
public class SitesList {

/** Variables */
private ArrayList<String[]> part = new ArrayList<String[]>();

/**
 * In Setter method default it will return arraylist change that to add
 */
public SitesList(String c) {
    String[] comp = new String[1];
    comp[0] = c;
    part.add(comp);
    // company name is part(0)[0]
}

public String getCompany() {
    return this.part.get(0)[0];
}

public ArrayList<String[]> getPart() {
    return part;
}

public void addPart(String[] name) {
    part.add(name);
}

public String getName(int i) {
    return this.part.get(i)[0];
}

public String getComp1(int i) {
    return this.part.get(i)[1];
}

public String getComp2(int i) {
    return this.part.get(i)[2];
}

public String getComp3(int i) {
    return this.part.get(i)[3];
}

public int getSize() {
    return this.part.size();
}

}
```

Comment: This is way too much code for a SO question.  Please cut this down to the absolute minimum required to exhibit the problem (please read http://sscce.org).

Comment: Sorry, First time lol just making sure there was enough info to solve.

Comment: An equivalent question has been asked many, many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reusing `part`, i.e. you add it multiple times but overwrite its contents. `ArrayList` is innocent here :)

Change the adding part to this:

```
if (counter == 4) {
    sitesList.addPart(part);
    //create a new array
    part = new String[4];
    counter = 0;
}
```

Or, as of Java 6:

```
if (counter == 4) {
    //add a copy to the list
    sitesList.addPart(Arrays.copyof(part, part.length));       
    counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was starting to think something around that area but I couldnt find where the problem was.  I thought it was a static problem.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, the List's values are not changing when the next value is added, but the array `part` is changed. What I mean is, the List has, at each location, a *reference* to the *same* array, which you call part. In other words, the List does not actually copy of the object but stores something (think of it as a "variable") that refers to the object.

So naturally, if you change the object the List is referring to at any index, you will see those changes when you pull out of the List. To solve this problem, create a new array every time you add to the list explicitly using the `new` keyword (or you can `clone` the array every time you add).